# Using ajax only saves 1 image from ACF gallery in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the ACF gallery field to let users create a gallery on front end and then I have an ajax call to save the gallery without page refresh.

If I remove the ajax save and use the default update post, all images in the gallery save correctly, but when I use my ajax save method only the last image in the gallery saves.

Here's my code:

Single post / form

```
<?php acf_form_head(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


  <?php $args = array( 

                          'form_attributes' => array(
                          'id'=>'modalAjaxTrying'

                          ),
                          'submit_value' => __("update this badboy",   'acf'),
                        );
            acf_form( $args );  


            ?>



<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php acf_enqueue_uploader();?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Ajax save in JS file

```
jQuery('form#modalAjaxTrying :submit').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var form_data = {'action' : 'acf/validate_save_post'};
 jQuery('form#modalAjaxTrying :input').each(function(){
 form_data[jQuery(this).attr('name')] = jQuery(this).val()
})


 form_data.action = 'save_my_data';
 jQuery.post(ajaxurl, form_data)
 .done(function(save_data){
 alert('Added successFully :');

 })
 })
```

Functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_my_data', 'acf_form_head' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_my_data', 'acf_form_head' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking to get ajax save to play nice with ACF gallery here ya go.

In your functions.php

```
add_action('acf/submit_form', 'my_acf_submit_form', 10, 2);
function my_acf_submit_form( $form, $post_id ) {

if(is_admin())
    return;

//Test if it's a AJAX request.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&    !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&   strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    echo $form['updated_message'];
    die();
 }

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_my_data', 'acf_form_head' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_my_data', 'acf_form_head' );

function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

// get new values
$value = get_field('add_images', $post_id);
```

In your JS file

```
acf.do_action('ready', $('body'));

$('form#modalAjaxTrying').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

 acf.add_action('submit', function($form){
 $.ajax({
  url: window.location.href,
  method: 'post',
  data: $form.serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    acf.validation.toggle($form, 'unlock');
            alert(data);
  }
 });
});
```